# Парсер PHP, как обойти загрузку?

Tags: php, парсер

Здравствуйте, мне нужно парсить сайт https://stepik.org/catalog но когда ты заходишь на неё у тебя начинается загрузка данных на сайт и из-за этого не могу парсить, как пройти эту загрузку а потом начать парсить? если есть возможность то буду благодарен за ссылку на статью

Comment: вы определились с тем, что конкретно вы хотите оттуда парсить? обходить загрузку эту не надо, ее надо использовать. Открываете ф12 инструменты брауера-сеть, обновляете страницу и смотрите, откуда тянуться данные в нужны блок. И отправляете запрос по тому же адресу. это даже удобнее.

Answer (score 1):

Для того как начать думать о парсе с ресурса, сначала попробуйте понять как работает данный ресурс. Ресурс пожгружает информацию с помощью `AJAX` технологии, если быть более бдительным, то можно заметить откуда загружаются данные:

`https://stepik.org/api/courses?exclude_ended=true&is_public=true&language=en&limit=6&order=-activity&page=1`

Благодаря этой ссылке вы получите данные в формате `JSON` и после перекодировки получите свои данные

Для пробы можете воспользоваться онлайн ресурсом `Json decoder` [Тут](http://jsoneditoronline.org/)

P.S Также можно изменять `GET` параметры и получать разные результаты, например `language` или `limit` и т.д